# Is there a way to give an unprivileged user access to Docker within Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vscode-remote, ddev, docker-in-docker

### Motivation

Running DDEV for a diverse team of developers (front-end / back-end) on various operating systems (Windows, MacOS and Linux) can become time-consuming, even frustrating at times.

Hoping to simplify the initial setup, I started working on an automated VS Code Remote Container setup.

I want to run DDEV in a VS Code Remote Container.

To complicate things, the container should reside on a remote host.

This is the current state of the setup: [caillou/vs-code-ddev-remote-container#9ea3066](https://github.com/caillou/vs-code-ddev-remote-container/tree/9ea3066d4b79459627bd2a8f556288b3a3a83d6a)

### Steps Taken

I took the following steps:

1. Set up VS Code to talk to a remote Docker installation over `ssh`. You just need to add the following to VS Code's `settings.json`: `"docker.host": "ssh://username@host"`.
2. Install `Docker` and create a user with `UID 1000` on said host.
3. Add `docker-cli`, `docker-compose`, and and `ddev` to the `Dockerfile`, c.f. [Dockerfile#L18-L20](https://github.com/caillou/vs-code-ddev-remote-container/blob/9ea3066d4b79459627bd2a8f556288b3a3a83d6a/.devcontainer/Dockerfile#L18-L20).
4. Mount the Docker socket in the container and use the remote user with `UID 1000`. In the example, this user is called `node`: [devcontainer.json](https://github.com/caillou/vs-code-ddev-remote-container/blob/9ea3066d4b79459627bd2a8f556288b3a3a83d6a/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json#L13)

### What Works

Once I launch the VS Code Remote Container extension, an image is build using the `Dockerfile`, and a container is run using the parameters defined in the `devcontainer.json`.

I can open a terminal window and run `sudo docker ps`. This lists the container I am in, and its siblings.

### My Problem

1. DDEV needs to create docker containers.
2. DDEV can not be run as root.
3. On the host, the user with `UID 1000` has the privilege to run Docker.
4. Within the container, the user with `UID 1000` does not have the privilege to run Docker.

### The Question

Is there a way to give an unprivileged user access to Docker within Docker?

Comment: Back in the day, there was https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind. But that's obsolete, and I haven't heard of any way to run docker inside docker in recent years.

Comment: Slowly getting there with `nestybox/sysbox`. Will write an answer, if I succeed that way.